# which cryptocurrency using Slasher algorithm for Proof of Stake mining process?

Tags: mining-theory, algorithms

Ethash algorithm for PoW mining process on my own cryptocurrency. I need to use Slasher algorithm instead of Ethash algorithm for Proof of Stake process.

My question is Which cryptocurrency using Slasher algorithm for Proof of Stake mining process?.
This answer is more helpful for my further process.

Answer (score -1):

etherieum, use the slasher 
you can see here:
https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/01/15/slasher-a-punitive-proof-of-stake-algorithm/